# django CurrencyField

Tags: django, forms, model

I am building a django app that requires some currency entries.  I am trying to make it easy to enter currencies and check that actual currencies are entered rather than just Decimal values.

In in my form, the field displays fine, but there there is some difficulty accepting legitimate values.  Here are my field errors.

1. Confusing -  If `max_digits=10`  how is this one possible?

   `entered:  50000.00   error:  Ensure that there are no more than 5 digits in total.`
2. Out of range value - How is this out of range?

   `entered: 50000  error: Out of range value for column 'amount' at row 1`

Any ideas what's happening here?

--------fields.py-------

```
class CurrencyField(models.DecimalField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def to_python(self, value):
        try:
           return super(CurrencyField, self).to_python(value).quantize(Decimal("0.01"))
        except AttributeError:
           return None
```

--------model.py---------

```
class Purchase(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, unique=False, editable=False)
    dtgPurchase = models.DateField('Date Purchased')
    amount = CurrencyField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
```

--------forms.py ---------

```
class PurchaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:  
        model = Purchase
        fields = ('dtgPurchase', 'amount',)
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you posted all the code for your CurrencyField class, but if this is your complete implementation it is missing some important methods.

Look at [this MoneyField](http://github.com/poswald/python-money/blob/master/money/contrib/django/models/fields.py) implementation for the other methods you need.

Comment: I tried out that MoneyField.  getting `Error: No module named contrib.django`   Ideas where to find this?

Comment: It looks like it is part of that project. Did you install the package so all the files are available? I.e `pip install -e git+http://github.com/poswald/python-money.git@0.0.1#egg=python-money`